# Dynamic File names in vars_files with inventory variables

Tags: ansible

Following is simple playbook

```
- name: Create VM and associated resources
  hosts: linux
  connection: local
  vars_files:
    - vars_files/{{ env_name }}_vars.yml
    - vars_files/base_vars.yml
  roles:
    - linux
```

And my inventory File is TEST.yml

```
all:
  vars:
    env_name: TEST
linux:
  hosts:
    TEST-SERVER:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.10
```

When I run the playbook ansible-playbook -vvv plabook_test.yml, I am receiving the following error.

**skipping vars_file 'vars_files/{{ env_name }}_vars.yml' due to an undefined variable**

Any Idea how can I used a variable from my inventory in the file name?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The inventory file is wrong because of the key "host"

```
all:
  vars:
    env_name: TEST
linux:
  host:
    TEST-SERVER:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.10
```

You should have seen a warning

> [WARNING]: Skipping unexpected key (host) in group (linux), only "vars", "children" and "hosts" are valid

Fix the inventory

```
all:
  vars:
    env_name: TEST
linux:
  hosts:
    TEST-SERVER:
      ansible_host: 10.10.10.10
```

Comment: Apologies for the typo error, my original inventory was in correct format.

Comment: Does the yml format require you to add `children:` under  `all:` and put `linux:` under children to make group `linux` a child of `all`?